# Which \bibliographystyle covers which BibTeX entries?

Tags: bibtex

I fail in finding overview of default bibliography styles. I am curious which is covering which fields. So far I know that difference between `alphaurl` and `alpha` is field `url`. What are other differences between style ?
I am exporting my collection to bibtex file, so I'd like to know which fields are going to stay, which are going to disappear.

Answer (score 6):

Indeed, there's a plethora of bibliography style files (extension .bst), but no central repository that lists what each of them does. The four "classic" .bst files -- thus-named because they came with the initial release of BibTeX -- are "plain.bst", "unsrt.bst", "alpha.bst", and "abbrv.bst"; see the [BibTeX manual](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/base) for information on these styles.

The "classic" style files were designed originally for numeric citation methods, but citation management packages such as [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/) and [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib) were developed that let you use these style files with author-year citation methods. The `natbib` package comes with `abbrvnat.bst`, `unsrtnat.bst`, and `plainnat.bst`, all of which recognize more fields -- including, you guessed it, the "url" field -- than the classic style files do.

The "classic" bst files recognize the following fields for an entry (of course, not all fields make sense for all entries):

```
address, author, booktitle, chapter, edition, editor, 
howpublished, institution, journal, key, month, note, 
number, organization, pages, publisher, school,
series, title, type, volume, year
```

The natbib bst files, in addition, recognize (i.e., "know what to do with") the following five fields:

```
doi, eid, isbn, issn, url
```

Assuming that quite a few of your entries will have url and doi fields, I recommend you go for one of the newer bst files rather than stick with the classic ones.

A big plus of the `natbib` package (which lets you do both numeric and auhor-year type citations, by the way) is that it works very well with the `hyperref` package. If `hyperref` is a package you're contemplating using, but if you're already using `harvard` and don't want to re-write all citation commands just to conform to the natbib syntax, don't despair: From now on, just load both the `natbib` and `har2nat` packages (and don't load the `harvard` package anymore). The `har2nat` package, you guessed it, translates the "harvard"-style citation commands into "natbib"-style citation commands...